# AWS S3 - permission to edit bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I recently created an S3 bucket on AWS through the console, with the default settigns (except the name, obviously). I try editing the Bucket Policy, but getting this error: "Error Access denied", both with my admin IAM user, and the root account.

How can I get access to edit S3 Bucket policies?

[image: Access dennied error]

Comment: Can it be solved by attaching  arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess policy to your user?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. Note: my user also has the AdministratorAccess policy attached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question: by default, buckets have the following option set: "Block new public bucket policies". Turning this off will enable updating the Bucket Policy.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, but please tell us how to turn off this setting.