# AWS Policy Generator creating invalid JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a policy using the policy generator and the produced file always fails validations.

Is there anything wrong with the file, or is the generator broken?

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "stmt1657969589793",
            "Effect": "ALLOW",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:750383375762:identity/exophrenik@gmail.com",
            "Action": [
                "ses:SendEmail",
                "ses:SendRawEmail",
                "ses:SendTemplatedEmail",
                "ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:ses:eu-central-1:750383375762:identity/exophrenik@gmail.com"
                ]
            },
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Have you gone through this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53457099/aws-s3-permission-to-edit-bucket-policy

Comment: Perhaps remove the empty Condition?

Answer (score 1):

With a small change, it worked for me.

Did you use Policy Generator from SES itself or from IAM?
It worked for me from SES.
The change you need to make is - **Principal** should be your AWS Acc ID or IAM user ARN. But you have used ARN of verified identity there.

Follow these steps : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/sending-authorization-identity-owner-tasks-policy.html

One observation:
"Effect": "ALLOW" - is invalid in IAM policy generator, but "Allow" is valid.
But in SES' policy generator "ALLOW" is valid!